# git clone a repository with user different than my linux user

Tags: git, centos, gitlab

I am trying to clone a git repository configured in gitlab from a VM.
I can clone from my computer, but I cannot clone from the VM although I am using the same key.

The Linux session user in my computer is XX which is the user name configured in git, and the linux session user in the VM is YY.

The question is - can I make this work ? clone from a session user which is not configured in git ? can I somehow supply a user and a key?

I've tried to create the user XX in my VM and from there to clone with the same key configured in ~/.ssh and it worked.

Comment: You can usually specify the remote user name in the git URL.

Comment: You should be able to do: `git clone XX@server.com:/path/to/repo.git`

Comment: Cloning from GitLab should always be done as git user.

Comment: Just add the key for user YY to gitlab. I don't understand why you cannot do that.

Comment: thanks - i found out it was a local problem of mine, i was using vagrant and didnt forward the ssh to my local machine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the username used on the gitlab server that handles the SSH session is normally `git` and has nothing to do with what username you use yourself, this should work fine.

The URL of the remote is `git@server.com:/...` for both. Gitlab determines which Gitlab account to use by the SSH key that you use. If you use the same SSH key for both Linux user accounts (or different keys but both added to the same Gitlab user), they wil use the same Gitlab user account.